# why link is not working in html and how to solve it?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

When i click a 'add to cart' button, it shows a **blank page** instead of cart page.

product.html

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'cart:add_cart' product.id %}">Add to Cart</a>
```

cart.views

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1

        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Comment: Please show urls.py and cart_detail template. Also network tab log from chrome dev tools would be helpful (or similar info from django log) - what requests and responses occur after you click the link.

Comment: And you can try printing something for debug purpose in every possible code flow to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: please provide your app urls and main urls

Comment: @ManojTolagekar i have added both urls as an answer

Comment: @IvanStarostin i have added both urls as an answer

Comment: `as an answer` that "answer" will be deleted soon with reason "not an answer". Please edit your original question instead @alanantony. and urls.py is not the only thing I asked for.

Comment: @ManojTolagekar product.html link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/165pv_u9vASk9HoIS4XmZu538WPJO_Ozm/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is probably not concatenated correctly. Try to debug your URL that should be in the "href" attribute, and you will see that there is probably some mistake.

Comment: i have added both urls as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your main.urls, just add namespace in cart include.

let's add:

**main.urls:**

```
path('cart/',include('cart.urls',namespace='cart')),
```

**OR**

If above code doesn't work, try below code.

```
path('cart/',include(('cart.urls','url'),namespace='cart')),
```

And now this will work:

```
href="{% url 'cart:add_cart' product.id %}">
```

And see if it solves

Comment: this is the my project link.could you please check it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-zeke0PoRn4cEVFWIM4iILahxBtNb7u3/view?usp=share_link

Comment: ok i will try and tell you

Comment: I have solved it. and i found your mistake

Comment: what is it ?
is it a url error or something else

Comment: You were not getting cart screen after clicking on addtocart right?

Comment: yes can u solve it

Comment: In cart.html, you have added square bracket in the begining of else statement instead of curly brace. let's make it correct. you have added like this [% else %}. It should be like this: {% else %}

Answer (score 0):

[this is the result when i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBgq.png)
product.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block metadescription %}

         {{ product.description|truncatewords:155 }}


{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}
         {{ product.name }} -A&A store

    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row my_prod_row_class"
    <div class="mx_auto">
        <p><a href="{% url 'shop:allProdCat' %}">Home</a>|<a href="{{ product.category.get_url}}">{{product.category}}</a>|{{product.name}}</p>

    </div>
<div class="container">
<br>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center ">
        <div style="min-width:18rem">
            <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
         <div>
         <h1 class="my_prod_title">{{product.name}}</h1>
         <p>{{product.price}}$</p>
         <p class="my_title">product Description </p>
         <p class="text-justify my_prod_text">{{product.description}}</p>
         {% if product.stock <= 0 %}
         <p class="text-justify my_prod_text"><b>Out of stock </b></p>
         {% else %}
         <a class="btn btn-secondary"  href="{% url 'cart:add_cart'  product.id %}">Add to Cart</a>
          {% endif %}


     </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```